# smartctl/S.M.A.R.T usb pass-through for Patriot PXD?

Tags: usb-drive, ssd, smartctl

I have a NVMe USB ssd
`ID 13fe:2570 Kingston Technology Company Inc. Patriot Memory`
It has `Unknown USB bridge [0x13fe:0x2570 (0x5204)]`. Does anyone know what is the correct parameter for `smartctl -d` ? I tried `usbjmicron`, `sat`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first add quirk parameter to avoid UAS driver
https://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/SAT-with-UAS-Linux

Then use `-d sntjmicron`

```
#smartctl -a -d sntjmicron /dev/<device>

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Number:                       Patriot PXD
Serial Number:                      ...
Firmware Version:                   EDFM00.5
PCI Vendor/Subsystem ID:            0x1987
IEEE OUI Identifier:                0x6479a7
...
```